# Sorting after a join based only on the filtered associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Event Model with many time slots(from and to attributes which are datetime).

I am filtering Events based on whether its upcoming, past or current.

This is the query I have

```
Event.includes(:time_slots).by_upcoming.order("time_slots.from asc").distinct
```

Say I have two upcoming Events - Event1 (time_slots: yesterday 12:00-13:00 and tomorrow 12:00-13:00) and Event2 (time_slots: two days before 10:00-11:00 and day-after 10:00-13:00)

Since these qualify as upcoming events, I need Event1 to be listed before Event2 as the upcoming slot of Event1(tomorrow) happens before upcoming slot of Event2(day-after)

These are the scopes I have in the TimeSlot model

```
scope :future, -> { where(from: DateTime.current..DateTime.current+20.years) }
```

and in the Event model

```
scope :by_upcoming, -> { where(id: TimeSlot.future.map(&:event_id)) }
```

However with this, Event2 is listed before Event1 as earliest time slot is of Event2 i.e. two days before. How can I just order based on the results(time slots) that is filtered out with the scope(by_upcoming) and not all time slots?

Comment: Maybe just `.reverse` to the collection array does it?

Comment: That won't. Above two were just examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an extra where-condition in your by_upcoming scope to limit that query to only the upcoming TimeSlots.

This can for example be done like this:

```
scope :by_upcoming, -> { where(id: TimeSlot.future.map(&:event_id)).where('time_slots.from > ?', DateTime.current) }
```

If you do not want an explicit reference to 20 years in the future in your future scope, that can be written like this:

```
scope :future, -> { where('time_slots.from > ?', DateTime.current) }
```

The SQL generated by:

```
Event.by_upcoming.includes(:time_slots).order("time_slots.from asc").distinct
```

then becomes:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "events"."id", time_slots.from AS alias_0
FROM "events"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "time_slots" ON "time_slots"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE "events"."id" IN (1, 2)
AND (time_slots.from > '2018-08-18 11:40:44.785860')
ORDER BY time_slots.from asc

SELECT DISTINCT "events"."id" AS t0_r0, "events"."name" AS t0_r1, "events"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "events"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "time_slots"."id" AS t1_r0, "time_slots"."from" AS t1_r1, "time_slots"."to" AS t1_r2, "time_slots"."event_id" AS t1_r3, "time_slots"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "time_slots"."updated_at" AS t1_r5
FROM "events"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "time_slots" ON "time_slots"."event_id" = "events"."id"
WHERE "events"."id" IN (1, 2) AND (time_slots.from > '2018-08-18 11:40:44.785860')
AND "events"."id" IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY time_slots.from asc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And yeah, I didn't need the explicit scope for 20 years. :)